# Can Colorbox auto resize based on text?

Tags: jquery, resize, colorbox

Is there a way to set Colorbox so that when text changes within the “pop up box” the box will auto resize based on the new text?

For instance, you have an accordion with varying amounts of text depending on which heading or subheading in the accordion you click on. When you user expands or collapses different "levels" the pop up box automatically adjusts based on the shown or hidden text.

**Updated Question based on replies:**

My apologies for not explaining the better (I’m still new to jQuery). I shouldn’t have used an accordion as the example, as what we’re trying to do is really more of an FAQ.

Here’s what I’m trying to do.

When the first “colorbox come up, it will have 3 topics (each a single sentence) in it.

When you click on each topic, it would lead you to anywhere from 1 to 3 paragraphs explaining that particular topic.

The challenge is that not only will there be a varying number of paragraphs in each “answer,” but they will be of different lengths and the colorbox needs to resize to accommodate each.

And, when you click back to the list of 3 topics, the colorbox has to resize to fit just those 3 single sentence paragraphs.

We haven’t written the code yet, as we’re trying to get this part right, first.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You may be able to call `$.colorbox.resize()` after content is changed. Can we see your code? A jsfiddle is even better.

Comment: if you look here and view source: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/ you can see transition effects on photos sharing a group1 classname.  I imagine it would work with divs with some adjustments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok - here is a redesigned answer

jQuery code for a colorbox that automatically resizes based on jQueryui accordion content:

```
$(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        heightStyle: 'content',
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        activate: function( event, ui ) {
            $.colorbox.resize();
        }
    });
});

$(".inline").colorbox({
    inline: true,
    innerWidth: '90%',
    scrolling: false      
});
```

[And the associated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GLWB6/)

Comment: I've updated the question, as I definitely picked he wrong example. Sorry for the confusion. Also, I couldn't find where they were using resize in the example you sent me to on the Colorbox site. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: my fault - the example I was referring to was on the jqueryui accordion example site where they were using an accordion within a resizable window.  I just took that example and combined it with the colorbox inline example to see how that would work.  The point was that yes, you can use an accordion inside a colorbox - after that it's *should* be just a matter of finding the right configuration options to get it to behave as you'd like.  I'll go look at your rephrased question and see if I can help.

Comment: Thanks. I know just enough to be dangerous, so really appreciate the help...:-)

Comment: I'm confused...:-) Why are you using the accordion method if I'm not creating an accordion?

Comment: Because it lends itself perfectly to the FAQ style Q&A text boxes that you are looking to implement.  That fiddle does everything you're looking for.  I guess I'm misinterpreting what you're trying to do.  When you say, *"When you click on each topic, it would lead you to anywhere from 1 to 3 paragraphs explaining that particular topic."* What does "lead" mean?

Comment: Are you saying the questions are links and the answers are to appear in a colorbox?

Comment: My apologies for not explaining this well. What I'm picturing is when you click on any of the topics, the others topics go away and are replace by the paragraph, so we'd be using Show and Hide as opposed to an accordion. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes - i see now. one last try :) give me a few minutes

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GLWB6/4/) Keep in mind that you will have to go to the colorbox website to pick a formatting style.

Comment: Can't thank you enough! Being pulled into a meeting, but will test as soon as I can.

Comment: I'm clearly missing something or have made an error in the code. I put it online in a Joomla Template (that I know works with colorbox and jquery without any conflicts) here: [link](http://www.moderntimesmediainc.com/test/colorbox-resize), but as you'll see the color box doesn't pop up. If you have the time, could you look at the code and see what I'm missing? Thanks in advance for any help you can be.

Comment: you added the ready() event...either wrap ALL the code in the ready() event, which is probably best, or move the script block after the hidden div

Comment: also, you should not be embedding the jquery and colorbox js modules in the middle of the body, they should be in the head

Comment: I set it to 90% arbitrarily, you can set it to whatever value you prefer for your site.  Keep in mind that you want the colorbox to be resized based on the dimmensions of the respective questions and answers so you should not specify a Height, however you need to determine a starting width.  It would not do to have the width so narrow as to make reading impossible. 50% is a good starting point, go from there.  Also: you can add a maxWidth/maxHeight option to set boundaries

Comment: Terrific. Thanks so much for your help!